# how to check username and email existence into database via ajax in code-igniter?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

this is my registration form..

```
<?php echo form_open('reg_ctrl/send_validation_email', array('class' => 'form-horizontal','role' => 'form'));?>
   <div class="form-group has-feedback">
     <label for="inputUserName" class="col-sm-4 control-label">User Name <span class="text-danger small">*</span></label>
       <div class="col-sm-8">
       <?php echo form_input(array('class'=>'form-control','type'=>'text','required'=>'email', 'id' => 'user_name', 'name' => 'user_name', 'placeholder' => 'User Name')); ?><i class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback"></i> 
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group has-feedback">
     <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Email <span class="text-danger small">*</span></label>
       <div class="col-sm-8">
       <?php echo form_input(array('class'=>'form-control','type'=>'email','required'=>'email', 'id' => 'email', 'name' => 'email', 'placeholder' => 'Email')); ?><i class="fa fa-envelope form-control-feedback"></i>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-group btn-default btn-animated">Sign Up <i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
     </div>
   </div>                                   
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

which accept username and email and in my case both unique so i want to display an existence that username and email in available or not before press the submit button like gmail registration.

I think i should have to integrate ajax in this and i am new to ajax please help me..

1) tablename:- registration    2) column name:- user_name and email

Thank You

Comment: use codeigniter validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.
This should call a script to your server, which could create a response after checking the database.

```
$("#user_name").change(function(event){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "CheckUsername.php",
    data: { 'username': $("#user_name").val() },
    success: function(data){
                     if(data == "available")   //this you would be your response
                          //do something
},
    error: function (httpRequest, status, error) {
        return false;
    }

});
```

});

The php file would just contain something like this

```
<?php
    //the username you send with
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    //check username in database.

    //When you are done, you echo the result out.
    echo $result;
?>
```

i hope this gives some clarity, otherwise you are welcome to ask for clarification.

EDIT: I just realised that you were talking about the event firing every time the user presses a button, in which case, this should work, although i haven't had the chance to test it.
Although this may not be good for low bandwidth users/servers as it calls the server every time you make a change.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#user_name").on('keyup change', function() {
                $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CheckUsername.php",
        data: { 'username': $("#user_name").val() },
        success: function(data){
                         if(data == "available")   //this you would be your response
                              //do something
    },
        error: function (httpRequest, status, error) {
            return false;
        }

    });


});
```

})​

Comment: i should have to send data for existence in controller function...and i don't know how? and i want this before user press the submit button..i mean they know username is available or not as soon they complete there input for username..\

Comment: That's exactly what this does. everytime you change the value in the textbox with id user_name it runs the ajax script, and calls your server. however as i don't know how your database is set up i can't write the sql for you, but you could do something like this. SELECT username FROM usere WHERE username = '{$username}'. then just check if it returns any rows. if it does there is already a user with that username, otherwise there isn't

Comment: I think i misunderstood your question, so i've updated my answer. The difference between these two is that the first one checks when the input field looses focus (you change to another field) and the second one fires every time you press a button.